# Vlookup/index/match with two datasets on two sheets

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

I have two data sets across two worksheets.  The first worksheet contains sales order numbers (Sheet1:column A) and other data .  The second worksheet contains sales order numbers (Sheet2:column A) and the product details.

On sheet1, I had to manually duplicate a sales order number (inserting another row) if the number of units of the order is greater than 1.  I then need to fetch the product details from sheet2 for each unit for that specific order number.  However in sheet2, there are multiple products for one sales order number.

How do i create a lookup/match to fetch the product details for each sales order number without duplicating the product details if there are multiple products for one sales order number?

I know a simple vlookup function will return the values that it matches first and that is not what i want.

**Example: Sheet1**

```
Column A (Sales Order#)      Column B (Quantity)     Column C (Product)  Column D (Serial Number)
0417436GPCP                  1
0417436GPCP                  1
0413412FACY                  1
0413412FACY                  1
```

**Sheet2**

```
Column A (Sales Order#)    Column B (Product)    Column C (Serial Number)

0417436GPCP                Door                  A13251
0417436GPCP                Window                A41315
0415835PTVX                Door                  C3431414
0412815PAIB                Door                  D1441412   
0413412FACY                Window                B41141
0413412FACY                Lock                  A4114151
0529834RWNY                Lock                  152141
```

**Ideal Output**

```
Column A (Sales Order#)  Column B (Quantity)  Column C (Product)  Column D (Serial Number)

0417436GPCP              1                    Door                A13251
0417436GPCP              1                    Window              A41315
0413412FACY              1                    Window              B41141
0413412FACY              1                    Lock                A4114151
```

Comment: Please format your sample data using the "code" {} button so it's more readable.  Did the first block for you...

Comment: ordering is not consistent and there are a lot more sales order numbers in Sheet2 that I don't need for Sheet1.

Comment: Basically, i need the formula to return MULTIPLE corresponding values for ONE Lookup Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Step 1:** In Sheet1, Insert a new column before Column A (this will shift the original column A to the right, making it now Column B
- **Step 2:** In the new column A, insert formula =COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2) and drag the formula down to the last row of the worksheet.
- **Step 3:** Repeat steps 1 and 2 in Sheet2, adjusting the COUNTIF formula criteria to reflect the column to be counted.  In this case, the formula should be =COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2)
- **Step 4:** In Sheet1, in column D (originally column C), insert the following formula;

  =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$8, MATCH($B2&"-"&$A2,INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$8&"-"&Sheet2!$A$2:$A$8, 0), 0)),"")
- **Step 5:** In Sheet1, In column E (originally column D), insert the formula from column D and adjust the first index formula criteria to reflect the column from Sheet2;

  =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$D$2:$D$8, MATCH($B2&"-"&$A2,INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$8&"-"&Sheet2!$A$2:$A$8, 0), 0)),"")
- **Step 6:** Drag down the formulas for each column

`